# Add button in devexpress NET MAUI Data Grid

Tags: datagrid, devexpress, maui

How can I add a button to the devexpress datagrid view.On clicking the button I need to show another page on the selcted row.

I tried creating an unbound column and I am not able to chose the column type for button and find specific event for the button click

Comment: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t265620/buttons-in-the-xamarin-grid-control

Comment: Have tried that solution but it helps to add an image column with an unbound column.it won't help to add a button or listen to the click event on the particular column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TemplateColumn.DipslayTemplate](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid.TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate) property to add a button to a column:

```xml
<dxg:TemplateColumn IsReadOnly="true" AllowSort="False" MinWidth="60">
    <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Button/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
</dxg:TemplateColumn>
```